# Query string after the domain name

Tags: http, url, uri

I am trying to add a query string at the end of URL for a hyperlink control as follows

```
HyperLink testLink = new HyperLink();
testLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.example.com" + "?siteId=asd343s32kj343dce";
```

But when this is rendered in the browser it is displaying as 
`http://www.example.com/?siteId=asd343s32kj343dce` (`/` char after the `.com`).

And if the `testLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.example.com/abc.aspx" + "?siteId=asd343s32kj343dce";`

Then the link is rendered correctly as `http://www.abcd.com/abc.aspx?siteId=asd343s32kj343dce` (No extra characters).

Am I missing any thing? Please advice.

Thank you,
Krishna.

Comment: Why do you think that `www.blah.com?myparam=val` should be valid? It looks pretty non standard to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The browser is correcting the URL for you by assuming that there should be a slash after the domain name. You might run into problems with browsers that doesn't do this, so you should correct the URL to:

```
testLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.abcd.com/" + "?siteId=asd343s32kj343dce";
```

The reason that the slash should be after the domain name is that the domain name itself can not be a resource. The domain name just specifies the web site, the URL has to have something that specifies a resource on that site, and the slash specifies the default page in the root folder of the site.

Answer (score 3):

this is normal, the **/** tell that the domain name ended and you are now inside the structure of the website (root context in this case).

the second one is normal because abc.aspx is a webpage and it can accept querystring. a domain cannot accept a querystring.

Answer (score 2):

```
An HTTP URL takes the form:

http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>

where <host> and <port> are as described in Section 3.1. If :<port>
is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
allowed.  <path> is an HTTP selector, and <searchpart> is a query
string. The <path> is optional, as is the <searchpart> and its
preceding "?". If neither <path> nor <searchpart> is present, the "/"
may also be omitted.
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.3

Answer (score 0):

Although `http://example.com?query` is a valid URI. The [normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.3) of HTTP URIs states that `http://example.com?query` and `http://example.com/?query` are equal:

> […] because the "http" scheme makes use of an authority component, has a default port of "80", and defines an empty path to be equivalent to "/", the following four URIs are equivalent:
>
> ```
>   http://example.com
>   http://example.com/
>   http://example.com:/
>   http://example.com:80/
> ```
>
> In general, a URI that uses the generic syntax for authority with an empty path should be normalized to a path of "/".